# Session object always returns null in asp mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I'm developing a website in asp mvc but i'm having trouble with Session objects.

i have this class for managing sessions,with a property for storing the language:

public class SessionManager
{

```
    public static string Language
    {
        get
        {              

           object language = GetSession("LANGUAGE");

            if (language != null)
            {
                return language as string;
            }
            return "EN";

        }
        set
        {               
            SetSession("LANGUAGE", value);     
        }
    }

    //methods for creating session objects

    private static bool SetSession(string key, object value)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static object GetSession(string key)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

}

When i want to change the language i call a method from HomeController
that sets the new language:

```
 public  void SetLanguage(string language)
    {                    
        SessionManager.Language = language;

    }
```

But the problem is the Session doesnt store the new value, it always returns null in the SessionManager class.
Why it is null? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static classes and static instance fields are shared between all requests in the asp.net mvc. Sessions should be unique per user. It means that you should **avoid static** keyword in the scope of sessions.

Also keep in mind, that static instances will not be cleared from the memory before the application pool is recycled. This can lead to memory usage problems.

I have tried your code and find out the working approach.
Reworked SessionsManager example

```
public class SessionManager
{
    private HttpContextBase _context;

    public SessionManager(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public string Language
    {
        get
        {

            object language = GetSession("LANGUAGE");

            if (language != null)
            {
                return language as string;
            }
            return "EN";

        }
        set
        {
            SetSession("LANGUAGE", value);
        }
    }

    private bool SetSession(string key, object value)
    {
        if (_context != null && _context.Session != null)
        {
            _context.Session[key] = value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private object GetSession(string key)
    {
        if (_context != null && _context.Session != null)
        {
            return _context.Session[key];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can use your manager in this way

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var sm = new SessionManager(HttpContext);
        ViewBag.Language = sm.Language;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SetRu()
    {
        var sm = new SessionManager(HttpContext);
        sm.Language = "Russian";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SetUa()
    {            
        var sm = new SessionManager(HttpContext);
        sm.Language = "Ukrainian";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

This code works fine and cover your needs

Comment: Remove static from your methods and create an instance of the SessionManager class every time when you want to get/set session's data

Comment: I have updated my answer with a code example. Please, try it out

Comment: Thank you,it works in the begining but the RedirectToAction causes to refresh again and then it looses the value.

Comment: I have tested my code (even added a new page). The new value of language stores in the right way between requests. May be something wrong with your project configurations? Try to use my sample in the default ASP.NET MVC project..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it was my fault because i was calling the actionresult from an ajax method, but it works now :)